# What's the purpose of the first return value of chaincode Invoke?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

The Invoke method of the Chaincode interface returns two values:

```
Invoke(stub *ChaincodeStub, function string, args []string) ([]byte, error)
```

[source](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/bcdb9c9bb11c500edafe6ac5d23df4d0dea2eeac/core/chaincode/shim/chaincode.go#L59)

However, the first return value seems to be ignored. In examples, it's always set to `nil`, and there doesn't seems to be any way to retrieve the value after the validation of the transaction (not included in blocks).

Is it the expected behavior? If yes, why does this return value exists?

There is another way to save this value, by emitting an event using `stub.SetEvent`, but that's quite unpleasant when a direct return value seems to exist.

Comment: Don't give a link to entire code, copy/paste here relevant code for your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the existing samples are trivial and return nil. probably not ideal, but they are what they are, presently. However, the purpose is to provide for an Invoke to return a response value.

Answer (score 1):

There is a use case for this return value. Namely, if you are calling one chaincode from within another. In this case, the return value will be passed to the first chaincode, allowing it to do processes based on the response.

For instance consider a user invoking chaincode A through the below method, which in turn invokes B.

```
func (t *ChaincodeA) Invoke(stub *shim.ChaincodeStub, function string, args []string) ([]byte, error) {
    //DO stuff
    valFromB, err := stub.InvokeChaincode("ChaincodeBDeployName", "someFunc", args)

    fmt.Println(string(valFromB))
    return nil,nil
}
```

Here's chaincode B for reference

```
func (t *ChaincodeB) Invoke(stub *shim.ChaincodeStub, function string, args []string) ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte("This is a value from B"),nil
}
```

This should print the below to the console when executed, showing that the value has been received:

> This is a value from B

Comment: Ok, so calls are synchronous between chaincodes. Thanks, that's not obvious.